# PowerShell: Checking for Loaded Assembly before trying to Load it again ('Assembly with same name is already loaded')

Tags: powershell, .net-6.0

I am operating in a PowerShell 7 SDK environment (runspaces provided by a .NET application utilising it) and I am manually loading in .NET DLLs to use their functionality using the following code:

```powershell
if(([System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | Where-Object { $_.ManifestModule.Name -eq 'HtmlAgilityPack.dll' }).Count -eq 0) {
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\ProgramData\ExampleApp\HtmlAgilityPack.dll") | Out-Null
}
```

This code is executed in multiple runspaces in the same .NET instance, however, I eventually get the error:

```
Assembly with same name is already loaded
```

Clearly my check to see if it's already loaded is not working properly, what is the correct check?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if one of the classes from the Assembly is already loaded with `GetAssembly` and only load the assembly if that fails:

```
try
{
    $null=[System.Reflection.Assembly]::GetAssembly([Kusto.Data.KustoConnectionStringBuilder])
}
catch
{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$(Get-Location)\bin\Kusto.Data.dll") | Out-Null
}
```